# Unable to use Resource Functions for Azure Resource Manager Templates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

My parameters file looks as follows:

```
    {
       "$schema":"http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
       "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
       "parameters":{
          "siteName":{
             "value":"my-api-application"
          },
          "appServicePlanName":{
             "value":"MyServicePlan"
          },
          "siteLocation":{
             "value":"West US"
          },
          "vaultResourceGroup": {
            "value":"my-vault-res-group"
          },
          "vaultName": {
            "value":"my-keyvault"
          },
          "nodeEnv": {
            "value":"development"
          },
          "adminPassword": {
            "reference": {
              "keyVault": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/yyyyyyyy-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyy/resourceGroups/my-vault-res-group/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/my-keyvault"
              },
              "secretName": "adminPassword"
            }
          }
       }
    }
```

The **adminPassword** value will be picked up from the specified ***KeyVault***, with the particular ***id***.  However, I have to hard code the **"id"** value.
According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid), I could specify the id using some thing like this:

```
resourceId(subscription().subscriptionId, parameters('vaultResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaultName'))]
```

However, when using the above syntax/Resource Functions, I receive an error while releasing and deploying my App Service using the **VSTS** (I used ***Azure Resource Group Deployment*** task for APP deployment). The error is some what like this:

> The id must be of the following format:

```
/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/{resourceType}/{resourceName}
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the result if you deploy it through PowerShell manually on your local machine? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-deploy-template-powershell

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong, that's intentional.  You must use a literal resourceId in the parameters file (parameters files don't allow for function use).

If you have a scenario for a dynamic KeyVault id you can use a nested deployment:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter#reference-a-secret-with-dynamic-id